# WPF structure to select usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a new WPF (.net core) project.  I have a main window what has a menu and status bar.  The DataContext is a viewmodel that does all the logic.  The body of the main window is a  contentcontrol            in which I switch in various usercontrols based on the operation being performed.
So far so good ...
I wish to call a command in the viewmodel when a menu item is selected.  Problem is - how do I access the MyContentControl in the mainwindow from the viewmodel?  I know that referencing the view from the vm is not recommended but I need to load a different user UI in response to various menu selections.

An example of this might be to show the EditPersonControl when the user selects EditPerson from the view menu.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that you want to do is called view location - you achieve this without referencing view from VM.

Shortest way would be to have a property like `BaseViewModel CurrentViewModel {get;set;}` (setter should raise property changed event) in the viewModel behind your main window.

This ViewModel only logic should be selecting other view-models to display by putting them in CurrentViewModel. You can also replace this by your framework's navigation service

(If you are not using one, you are missing big time)

Then in view you can setup your content control like this:

```
 <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
<ContentControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:FirstViewModel}">
        <views:FirstView ViewModel={Binding}/> 
        <!-- <views:FirstView DataContext={Binding}/>  -->
        <!-- The first method is preferable -->
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SecondViewModel}">
        <views:SecondView ViewModel={Binding}/> 
    </DataTemplate>

     <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:AnotherViewModel}">
            <views:AnotherView ViewModel={Binding}/> 
        </DataTemplate>
    <ContentControl.Resources>
  </ContentControl>
```

I hope you can see the pattern here - the control will select proper template based on the specific type that you put in `CurrentViewModel`. You can also put those templates in app.xaml in `App.Resources` and then all ContentTemplates and ItemTemplates will use them automatically. In this case, you can overwrite them locally in each control's resources if needed.

Of course, this means that you have to add all available views as templates.

Because this is very tedious, we have frameworks. I've used only [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-location/), which is able to find all views automatically, but I'm pretty sure that other frameworks also support this concept.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it without corrupting the integrity of the model.
I added a property in the VM to hold the user control to be displayed and then bound "{Binding BodyContentProperty}"

The View stays independent.  The VM does not know about the view.  I think this is acceptable.

Comment: if ViewModel has a property of type `UserControl` then MVVM is violated, but I hope I just misunderstood your response